# If a manifold is locally flat, how can we detect curvature by local parallel transport?

Tags: general-relativity, curvature

My understanding is that curvature of a manifold can be defined by the usual procedure of parallel-transporting an object around a loop and taking the limit as that loop's area goes to zero. However, it is also true that a manifold is locally flat, i.e. flat in the infinitesimal region around a given point.

How do these things not contradict each other? How can the manifold be flat in an arbitrarily small region around a point but also exhibit curvature by PT-ing a vector around an arbitrarily small loop around that same point?

My context here is GR, so just assume properties of manifold needed for GR purposes.

Answer (score 2):

The manifold is locally flat in the sense that the first derivatives of the metric can always be set to zero by choosing a suitable coordinate system known as Riemann normal coordinates.

However, the second derivatives of the metric cannot all be set to zero with coordinate transformations. The number of second derivatives that cannot be set to zero is precisely the number of independent ways in which the manifold can curve. In $n$ dimensions, this is
$$\frac{1}{12} n^2 \left(n^2-1\right)$$

The Riemann tensor involves second derivatives of the metric because parallel transporting a vector around a loop requires applying a double covariant derivative.

Comment: Ok, so just to clarify, is this the same sense in which a parabola is "flat" where its first derivative vanishes, i.e. because its value does not change to first order at that point?

Comment: @nothingIsMere Yes, that's correct.